# At which height should the net be kept b/w the poles in badminton?

Tags: rules, badminton

What is the height of the upper edge of the net from the court in badminton game?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is obtained directly from reading the rules with no further interpretation or discussion required. Sports SE is not a replacement for making an effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the the [Laws of Badminton](https://extranet.bwfbadminton.com/docs/document-system/81/1466/1470/Section%204.1%20-%20Laws%20of%20Badminton.pdf):

> §1.10 The top of the net from the surface of the court shall be 1.524 metres at the centre of the court and 1.55 metres over the side lines for doubles.

In competition play, the netposts are exactly on the side lines for doubles.